# How do you access base object Array in a JavaScript Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm only posting relevant code here. I'm trying to access an array in a json array. How do I access an array inside an array?

So this is the code serverside :

```
$scriptfull = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultstmt_scriptfull)) {
        $scriptfull[] = $r;
    }

$resulterr = array('message' => 'Success',
                                 'fullscript'=>$scriptfull);
                    header('Content-Type: application/json');
                    echo json_encode($resulterr);
```

I know how to access JSON array in Javascript. The problem I do not know how to access a base object that is itself an array within a JSON array.

When I do :

```
success: function(output)
{
console.log(output.fullscript);
}
```

I see result in console

```
(1)[...]
     0:{...}
        scriptAA1: "a1"
        scriptAA10: "a10"
​​        scriptAA2: "a2"
​        scriptAA3: "a3"
```

But nothing prints in the HTML if I try

```
  success: function(output)
    {
    $('.scriptview').html(output.fullscript);
    }
```

I tried accessing it using below code but nothing prints:

```
 success: function(output)
        {
        $('.scriptview').html(output.fullscript[1]);
        }
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript question, not a JSON question -- JSON has no idea of a "base object" at all. (Yes, JSON is a subset of JavaScript, but this question goes outside that subset's bounds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is trying to print a javascript array of objects at html which of course does not make sense and that why nothing is printed. You can either print the javascript array as a string (which probably is not what you want) like this:

```
$('.scriptview').html(JSON.stringify(output.fullscript));
```

I think you should explain better what exactly you are trying to print to html.

Edit:
As I understood you want something like what you are getting in your console. For something like this, the code below will do:

```
var outputString = '';

output.fullscript.forEach(function(object, index){
    outputString += '<br> Object with index: ' + index + '<br>';
    for (var prop in object){
       outputString += 'Property ' + prop + ': ' + object[prop] + '<br>';
    }
});

$('.scriptview').html(outputString);
```

Comment: I'm just wanting to print the result for humans in an html div. I want to print what I see in the console log. Your answer prints this `[object Object]`

Comment: I have updated my answer to get a more human readable output.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to output the result as a string, you can use

```
success: function(output)
{
    $('.scriptview').html(JSON.stringify(output.fullscript));
}
```

### Update1

If you want the result formatted with whitespaces, the 3rd argument of the `stringify` method does that:

```
success: function(output)
{
    $('.scriptview').html(JSON.stringify(output.fullscript, null, '\t'));
}
```

### Update2

A more shorter, readable and efficient way is to just display using the jQuery `text` method instead of `html`:

```
success: function(output)
{
    $('.scriptview').text(JSON.stringify(output.fullscript, null, '\t'));
}
```

This looks more tidy...

Comment: Yes Thanks this works but I would like it to print like I see in the console all stacked up vertically instead of one liner.

Comment: @Sadie I have added more to the answer